# Ansible : How to update file that opens in vim editor on running of a command

Tags: ansible, openshift, openshift-origin, okd

I need to update a file using ansible. In manual process of updating, when the edit command is ran, the file opens in a editor like vim, nano etc, where the changes are updated and saved.

i.e, 
Upon running of following command, a temp-file gets opened in editor specified in the command,
 `sudo OC_EDITOR="nano" oc edit configmap/webconsole-config -n openshift-web-console`

Note that each time when the command is ran the content gets opened in new temp files. Once the changes are updated the file gets saved into the docker container.

Since in the above command the editor is specified as `nano`, the file contents are opened in nano editor with content as follows:

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
apiVersion: v1
data:
  webconsole-config.yaml: |
    apiVersion: webconsole.config.openshift.io/v1
    clusterInfo:
      adminConsolePublicURL: https://console.router.default.svc.cluster.local/
      consolePublicURL: https://master.novalocal:8443/console/
      masterPublicURL: https://master.novalocal:8443
    extensions:
      properties: {}
      scriptURLs: []
      stylesheetURLs:[]
    features:
      clusterResourceOverridesEnabled: false
      inactivityTimeoutMinutes: 0
.
.
.
```

Here the `stylesheetURLs` needs to be updated in the file as follows:

```
.
.
      scriptURLs: []
      stylesheetURLs:
      - http://127.0.0.1:30296/css/logo.css
    features:
      clusterResourceOverridesEnabled: false
.
.
.
```

Here the `stylesheetURLs` needs to be updated with indentation as mentioned above and the indentation of the other content needs to be retained.

How could this be achieved in ansible playbook?

Additional info: The purpose of this is to update the webconsole logo of okd/openshift 3.11, Reference:https://docs.okd.io/3.11/install_config/web_console_customization.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question. The objective is not "how to I disable `$EDITOR`" but rather "how to I edit configs and then re-`apply` them," which is exactly what <strike>`kubectl edit`</strike> `oc edit` does for you: `oc get -o yaml  -n openshift-web-console configmap/webconsole-config > $TMPDIR/some-file.yaml && $EDITOR $TMPDIR/some-file.yaml && oc -n openshift-web-console apply -f $TMPDIR/some-file.yaml && rm $TMPDIR/some-file.yaml`

You will find a whole host of ansible mechanism that allow you to change the contents of a text file in a very precise way, so just reproduce that in your playbook, no "nano" required

```yaml
- set_fact:
    my_temp_path: /tmp/some-random-filename.yaml
- shell: >-
    oc get -o yaml -n openshift-web-console 
    configmap/webconsole-config >{{ my_temp_path }}
- lineinfile:
     path: '{{ my_temp_path }}'
     # whatever else
- command: oc -n openshift-web-console apply -f {{ my_temp_path }}
- file:
    path: '{{ my_temp_path }}'
    state: absent
```